# How to prevent Crash in Room DB migration, with problematic migration?

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

I'm using Room in my Android app, and provide some migrations.
in some migration I had a NOT NULL declaration, but at real time it's NULL...
and the app crashes !

I've tried the fallbackToDestructiveMigration before the DB build, but it didn't worked. it's not catching the IllegalStateException before it occurs, and the app crashes .

How can I prevent the app from crashing? even if it means all the  data will be removed.

thanks.

code below:

```
mAppDb = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                 .addMigrations(
                         MIGRATION_1_2,
                         MIGRATION_2_3,
                         MIGRATION_3_4
                  )
                 .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                 .build();
```

Comment: If you are adding new columns in new apk release and not changing the  version in database class. Then the app will crash

Comment: I upgrades the schema, it's not this...

Comment: can u show the log?